# how to dynamically change comment ModelForm in django

Tags: django, django-forms

I need to view comment ModelForm with fields = ('name', 'email', 'body'). When user is authenticated, field 'name' must be request.user.username and 'email' must be request.user.email.
When user is not authenticated user must insert his name and email.

What solution can i use here. how can i find information about this question?

Comment: you want an registration in your app ?

Comment: i need to add comment to article

Answer (score 1):

In your views.py

```
def comment_new(request):
if request.method == "POST":
    form = CommentForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        comm = form.save(commit=False)
        if request.user.is_authenticated:
            comm.username = request.user.username
            comm.email = request.user.email
        comm.save()
        return redirect('somewhere')
else:
    form = CommentForm()
return render(request, 'path_to_html', {'form': form})
```

Then in forms.py you can make name and email fields non required.

Also in html if you have auth user just do not show him name and email inputs